# Is it possible to invoke a function by clicking a part of string?

Tags: javascript

```
$("#chk_select").html("Sorry no such product. Click here to create one");
```

When the above line is displayed and if the user clicks on "Click here" I need javascript to invoke an action like `slideUp();`. Is it possible?

Comment: Wrap it in an element, and add an event. Also see http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12100/why-shouldnt-we-use-words-such-as-here-and-this-in-textlinks and http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7114/how-to-avoid-click-here-links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap that part of a string inside an element, like:

```
$("#chk_select").html("Sorry no such product. <span id='link'>Click here</span> to create one");
```

And then write a click handler

```
$("#link").click(function() {
   slideUp();
});
```

Or you can do

```
$("#link").on( "click", function() {
```

Comment: Thanks man worked like a charm!!!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to split string in 2 parts and wrap "Click here" in span. Then attach click handler to this span

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
$("#chk_select").html("Sorry no such product. Click here to create one").bind('click',function () {
    $(this).slideUp();
});
```

and when you want to hide/remove the text

```
$("#chk_select").html('').unbind('click');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FArKv/

**UPDATE:**

Since you just need to make a part of the text click and make all hide. use it like other says,

```
$("#chk_select").html("Sorry no such product. <a href='#' id='bind_click_here'>Click here</a> to create one");

$("#bind_click_here").bind('click',function () {
    $("#chk_select").slideUp();
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FArKv/1/

Comment: I think Krish Kaine want to slideUp the text after clicking only on "Click here" instead whole text.

Comment: @RakeshKumar, sorry my bad,

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak the HTML a little bit by adding an anchor and then add a click handler:

```
$("#chk_select")
    .html('Sorry no such product. <a href="#">Click here</a> to create one')
    .on('click', 'a', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // do your stuff
        $(event.delegateTarget).slideUp();
    });
```